# How can I get ctags to show the parameters for a given C function?

Tags: c, parsing, ctags

I'm trying to write a script that parses the functions in a file, and in particular, the parameters of each function.  So for example, if file X.c has function func(int a, char b), then I want to see output like

```
func
    int a
    char b
```

ctags gets me very close:

```
ctags -x --c-types=f file.c
```

shows me:

```
func function    106 file.c func
```

which is great, because file.c has a whole bunch of goofball macros and typedefs that confuse most C parsers.

So is there a way to get ctags to show the parameters for a given function?  All of the examples I've seen are for generating tag files, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to find the answer, but the trick is to use **ctags-universal**, which is an updated version of ctags.

> ctags-universal -x --c-kinds=f --_xformat="%N %S" *filename*

Comment: --kinds-c=f is preferred in the ctags implementation.